Google Referrer API in Android
Is there any strategy to get referrer parameter only one time?
not everytime when launch app.
Now, my app has referrer parameter data while app is installed.
I can't find any strategy to solve this problem. Is there any solution?

You can create an alreadyObtainedInstallReferrer flag and store it in SharedPreferences (or a similar storage mechanism). Whenever you obtain the referrer parameter, set alreadyObtainedInstallReferrer to true. Then, use an if condition to check this flag and avoid getting the install referrer again if it has already been obtained.
fun checkInstallReferrerInfo() {
        if (appPreferences.alreadyObtainedInstallReferrer) return

        referrerClient = InstallReferrerClient.newBuilder(context).build()
        referrerClient.startConnection(object : InstallReferrerStateListener {
            override fun onInstallReferrerSetupFinished(responseCode: Int) {
                when (responseCode) {
                    InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.OK -> {
                        Timber.d("Connection established.")
                        try {
                            obtainReferrerDetail()
                            appPreferences.alreadyObtainedInstallReferrer = true
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Timber.w("Could not obtain install referrer: ${e.message}")
                        }
                    }

                    InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED -> {
                        Timber.w("API not available on the current Play Store app.")
                    }

                    InstallReferrerClient.InstallReferrerResponse.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                        Timber.w("Connection couldn't be established.")
                    }
                }
                referrerClient.endConnection()
            }

            override fun onInstallReferrerServiceDisconnected() {
                Timber.d("Service disconnected.")
            }
        })
    }

